# Creating a walk through in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to add a "walk-through" mode to my existing `WPF` project which will guide the user through the process of using my application. Trying to look this up is difficult, because every Google search for "WPF walk through" returns a walk-through on how to use `WPF`!

I've thought of something like using tooltips and programmatically controlling when they are visible for each control in the GUI ("Press this button next, etc") but I'm hoping for suggestions on a better way as I'm still pretty new to `WPF`.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I would use Popup.

Just show same popup with different content near to interested controls

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check into it.

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to be looking for is a wizard... check this one out:

[Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wizard)

Comment: Not quite looking for a wizard, but this is definitely something I can use in the future. Thank you!